# I am trying to show count on specific name using laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I am trying to show count on specific name which is the left side menu name "property" but getting count show in all menus please help me how can i show count only on  property menu  using laravel 8

**helpers.php**

```
function propertyCount()
 { 

    $propertyModelPath = Menu::where('route', 
   'property')->where('count_show', 1)->first();

    $modelClass = $propertyModelPath->modal_path;

    $count = new $modelClass;

    return $count->count();
}
```

**left side bar menu**

```
<div id="sidebar-menu">
      <ul>
        @foreach ($menus as $menu)
          @if ($menu->parent_id == 0)
          <li class="has_sub">
            <a href="{{$menu->route == null ? 'javascript:void(0);' : route($menu->route)}}" class="waves-effect">
              <i class="{{$menu->icon}}"></i>
              <span> {{$menu->name}} {{propertyCount()}}  </span>
              @if ($menu->route == null)
              <span class='menu-arrow'></span>
              @endif
            </a>
          </li>
          @endif
        @endforeach
      </ul>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use like this

```
<span> 
    {{$menu->name}} 
    @if($menu->name=='property')
        {{propertyCount()}}  
    @endif
</span>
```